# Populate Primary Point of Contact Field ( Business Account ) from Contact Object

Tags: rest-api, contact, php, trigger, curl

I am using PHP cURL to populate data in the Customer, and the Account Object. I am working to link the two objects together via Contact Role. In which object field do I need to assign a value to in order to show the Primary Point of Contact for the Business Account? I am looking all over but so far all attempts with the Opportunity object, OpportunityContactRole, AccountContactRole, have yielded no result.

which Object do I need to use in order to make the Business Account Show the Primary Point of contact? ( See screenshot )

[image: This Spot Here]

Comment: Have you tried to populate the field isPrimary to true in associated contactrole record?

Comment: Yes. In the AccountContactRole. Account=$accountId, ContactId=$contactId, and IsPrimary=true. Maybe it's not a boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a combination of reasons this didn't work in my original post. Here is a link to the process.

Also the field "Primary Point Of Contact" wasn't available because it was a custom field Primary_Point_of_Contact__c.

[How to create a business account with the REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187863/how-to-create-a-business-account-with-the-rest-api/187866#187866)